# sequelize include not bringing a specific model

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

So I have this controller, and when I send a request to the post, the return object is missing the Converter model information, but when I send a get request, the return object does include the Converter models. I have checked the models, and the setttings of the association(many to many). I have checked the DB, and the associatins in the pivot table are there as well. Any idea why?

```
const { Router } = require("express");
const { Op } = require("sequelize");
const { 
  UnitProfileCard,
  Faction,
  UnitRank,
  UpgradeSlot,
  UpgradeCard,
  UpgradeCardType,
  UnitType,
  Keyword,
  Converter,
  Weapon
} = require('../db');

const unitProfileCardRouter = Router();

unitProfileCardRouter.get("", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const profileCards = await UnitProfileCard.findAll({
      order: [['unitName', 'ASC']],
      include: [
        {
          model: Faction,
          attributes: ["id", "name"],
        },
        {
          model: Keyword,
          attributes: ["id", "name", 'description'],
        },
        {
          model: UnitRank,
        },
        {
          model:UnitType,
          attributes: ["id", 'name'],
        },
        {
          model: UpgradeSlot,
          attributes: ["id"],
          include:[
            {
              model:UpgradeCard,
              attributes: ["id", 'name', 'cardDescription'],
              include:[
                {
                  model:UpgradeCardType,
                  attributes: ["id", 'name', 'icon'],
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              model:UpgradeCardType,
              attributes: ["id", 'name', 'icon'],
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          model: Converter,
          attributes: ["id", "convertee"],
        },
        {
          model: Weapon
        },
      ], 
    });
    res.status(200).send(profileCards);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error);
  }
});

unitProfileCardRouter.post("", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const {
      unitName,
      unitTitle,
      pointCost,
      unitSize,
      defense,
      speed,
      uniqueUnitAbilities,
      artworkUrl,
      //other models
      faction,
      rank,
      unitType,
      keybords,
      upgradeSlots,
      converters,
    } = req.body;

    const allTrue = [
      unitName,
      unitTitle,
      pointCost,
      unitSize,
      defense,
      speed,
      artworkUrl,
      faction,
      rank,
      unitType,
    ].every((prop) => prop);

    if (!allTrue) throw new Error("Missing property");

    let newCard = await UnitProfileCard.create({
      unitName,
      unitTitle,
      pointCost,
      unitSize,
      defense,
      speed,
      uniqueUnitAbilities,
      artworkUrl
    });
    // console.log(newCard);
    //set extras
    await newCard.setFaction(faction);
    await newCard.setUnitRank(rank);
    await newCard.setUnitType(unitType);
    if (keybords?.length > 0) {
      keybords.forEach(async k => {
        await newCard.addKeyword(k);
      });
    }
    let result = true;
    if (upgradeSlots?.length > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < upgradeSlots.length; i++) {
        let foundSlot = await UpgradeSlot.findByPk(upgradeSlots[i]);
        if (foundSlot) {
          await newCard.addUpgradeSlot(foundSlot);
        }
        else result = false;
      }
    }
    if (converters?.length > 0) {
      converters.forEach(async c => {
        await newCard.addConverter(c);
      });
    }

    newCard = await UnitProfileCard.findOne(
      {
        where:{ id:newCard.id },
        include: [
          { model: UpgradeSlot },
          { model: Converter, },
          { model: Keyword, }
        ]
      }
    );

    if (!result) return res.status(404).send({message:'Upgrade Slot ID not found'});
    res.status(200).send(newCard);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error.message);
  }
});

unitProfileCardRouter.delete("", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let {
      id
    } = req.body;

    if (!id) throw new Error("Missing property");

    const foundProfile = await UnitProfileCard.findOne(
      {
        where:{ id },
        include: [
          { model: UpgradeSlot },
          { model: Converter }
        ]
      }
    );
    if (foundProfile) {
      foundProfile.UpgradeSlots.forEach(async slot => {
        await UpgradeSlot.destroy({
          where:{id:slot.id}
        });
      });

      // console.log('AFTER FOREACH');
      await UnitProfileCard.destroy({
        where:{ id }
      }); 
      res.status(200).send({message:'Record Deleted'});
    }
    else res.status(404).send({message:'Record Not Found'});
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error.message);
  }
});

module.exports = unitProfileCardRouter;
```

Comment: Could it be that `converters?.length` is actually equal to 0 or undefined?